# Are all snubbers interchangeale?

Tags: snubber, transient-suppression

There are different kinds of snubbers that can be used. I know of 3, but there could be more.

- D
- RC
- RCD

If an certain circuit uses a diode, can I swap it for an RC ? Or if a circuit has an RC, can I swap it for a diode ? Are they interchangeable ?

If they are interchangeable, is cost the reason why one is chosen over the other or are there specific applications where one would be better suited over the other?

Comment: I know of RC snubbers, used mostly to soften the blow of a switching element like a FET. I saw it used in a fly-back pulsed power supply when I was an intern. The only reason i'd say a diode would be put in with the RC snubber is to clamp the snubbed voltage or prevent backwards feedback

Comment: A snubber is always a compromise. It absorbs unwanted energy or energy which is existing at times and places that adversely affects operation and either dissipates it or transfers it to somewhere less damaging or useful. While to some extent you can do the same sort of thing in different situations with one topology or in a given situation with various toplogies, there will usually be one arrangement which is optimum in a gavin case, and other arrangements which are not a good fit in some cases. Factors can include cost (which has various factors), affect on circuit operation operation, ... .

Comment: @RussellMcMahon any examples where one would be suited over another ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say no, since each snubber is designed to function for that circuit. An RC snubber across a switching supply winding is "tuned" to provide enough damping at that frequency; it couldn't work on a solenoid since it's values are almost certainly incompatible for that application. As far as the different types of snubber are concerned, this depends on what is allowable in the circuit and how much damping is required. There are even more types which become more complex, for specialty applications. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=electronic%20snubbers) has many hits on this topic, the first being a decent [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber) overview of snubbers.

Comment: I should have been clear in my question, that it wasn't taking an existing RC from one circuit and just plugging it in. The values if R and C would be have chosen so that it provides the same same function as another snubber. What the question was really asking is can anyone use any type of snubber for any application? Or are some types of snubber better suited for some applications and not the other

Answer (score 1):

Diode and RCD snubbers can only be used for DC circuits; all three types can be used there, and do the same basic job.  AC circuits require a RC snubber, though.  Also, TVS devices can be used for snubbing/transient suppression, or even a MOV in a pinch.